# Using xml-to-json. "Inner XML/XHTML" should go in a json string value field

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xpath, saxon

I'm using Saxon Home Edition to convert XML to JSON:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="xmljson">
            <map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
                <string key="name">Some name</string>
                <string key="description">A nice description</string>
            </map>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($xmljson)" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces the desired output:

```
{"name":"Some name","description":"A nice description"}
```

The description field contains arbitrary complex xhtml. The template rule **does not work** with the following description field:

```
<string key="description">A <strong>nice</strong> description</string>
```

Error message:

```
xml-to-json: unknown element <strong>
```

Enclosing the description in a CDATA section does work:

```
<string key="description"><![CDATA[A <strong>nice</strong> description]]></string>
```

Desired output:

```
{"name":"Some name","description":"A <strong>nice<\/strong> description"}
```

## Problem/Question

The content of the description field is the result of a transformation. So with and withou CDATA fails. **This will not work**:

```
<string key="description"><xsl:apply-template select="description" /></string>
```

Neither this:

```
<string key="description"><![CDATA[<xsl:apply-template select="description" />]]></string>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`serialize()` function](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-serialize) to produce escaped XML markup as text.

```
<xsl:variable name="options" as="element()">
  <output:serialization-parameters xmlns:output="http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization">
    <output:omit-xml-declaration value="yes"/>
  </output:serialization-parameters>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="xmljson" as="element()">
  <map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <string key="name">Some name</string>
    <string key="description"><xsl:value-of select="serialize(description, $options)"/></string>
  </map>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: This is the solution for my application based on XSLT 3.0/XPath 3.0/3.1. Thanks @Mads Hansen. Just wonder if their exists a similar solution for XSLT 2.0. XSLT 2.0 does not support an xml-to-json function, but one could come up with similar serialization needs, not related to xml-json conversion.

Comment: Yes, take a look at Evan Lenz XML-to-string converter stylesheet: http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following quick hack. Have to check this tomorrow again, kind of tired now...t

---

Edit: **This is a horrible hack!** The template rule does not treat special characters. Please read the comments below.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="doc">
            <description>A <strong class="red">nice</strong> description</description>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="xmljson">
            <map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
                <string key="description"><xsl:apply-templates select="$doc/description/text()|$doc/description/*" /></string>
            </map>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($xmljson)" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <!-- opening tag -->
        <xsl:text>&lt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <!-- attribute nodes -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <!-- closing tag -->
        <xsl:text>&lt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <xsl:text>="</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces the desired output:

```
{"description":"A <strong class=\"red\">nice<\/strong> description"}
```

Comment: Horrible hack. You're making no attempt to escape special characters. It's because people attempt homebrew serialization like this that we see so much broken XML on this site.

Comment: I thought it is obvious that the accepted answer from @Mads Hansen is the correct one. Perhaps it's not. So, what to do with the "horrible hack" Michael? Delete it? I probably will not have to go any deeper into XML/XSLT. So never will learn it. But just for curiosity. Which special characters have to be escaped? Please excuse the XML "very basic level".

Comment: In text nodes, `<` and `&` must be escaped as `&lt;` and `&amp;`. You also need to ensure that `>` is escaped as `&gt;` if it appears in the sequence `]]>`, though most people escape `>` everywhere to save effort. In attribute nodes, the attribute delimiter (`'` or `"`) must be escaped. I'm sorry, but I find it hard to excuse the "XML very basic level". We see so many problems on this site caused by people dabbling in technologies that they have made no effort to properly understand. If plumbers or electricians did this, we would all be dead by now.

Comment: With "very basic level" I meant the question, not the hack. Thanks for answering Michael. I got it. Never thought much about the escaping. Just used it. But with one point I do disagree. "to properly understand" in depth XSLT and related technologies like XPATH with all the ins and outs is not a trivial "some-days-task" for many people like me. But with a basic understanding and with the friendly help of more experienced people like You, it's still possible to achieve some results. At the end of the day, my task is resolved and as a goodie, I learned something. Not that bad at all :-) Thanks.